# What is correct form to configure UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using `ReusableCell` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like that;

```
    NSDictionary *cellData = [_cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *kCellID = @"homePage";
    _cell = (HomePageCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if(_cell == nil)
    {
        _cell = [[HomePageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellID withDictionary:cellData];
    }
    __weak typeof(_cell) weakSelf = _cell;
    [_cell.rootImageView setImageWithURLRequest:_cell.requestImage placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
        {
            weakSelf.rootImageView.image=image;
        }    failure:nil];
```

and my `rootImageView` object is configuring. My problem is start after scrolling like that;

In Cell-1 rootImageView.image should be Image-1
In Cell-2 rootImageView.image should be Image-2
In Cell-3 rootImageView.image should be Image-3

When i starting scroll and my code is coming out `if(_cell == nil)`, my all images turned back same image as Image-1. However, when i logged `[_cellArray description]`, data is totally true. What is the point i missed? Why all cell images turned back Image-1 after cell is not nil?

**EDIT :** This is really weird, if i don't use kCellID images are loading correct. I switched `_cell` property to `HomePageCell *cell`.

Comment: Did you try to log something inside the success block? When you scroll down, see the wrong image after the code inside of success block was executed, does image change?

Comment: Yes its changing as log and coming next image parameter according to indexPath.row but i see always same image.

Comment: Really, is _cell a local or instance variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have already pointed out, it looks like you’re storing `_cell` as an instance variable. Never do that, as each cell instance must be dequeued/created ‘on the fly’ as they are requested to be displayed onscreen.

If your `UITableViewCell` instance is a custom subclass (which I assume it is), you should override its `-prepareForReuse` method, where you should set the `imageView`’s `image` property to `nil`. Otherwise you could assign it a `nil` value in your `-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation.

Also, because of the way that cells are quickly queued/reused/discarded, you should check that you are assigning the requested image by the time it arrives from the network to the right cell. To do so, instead of keeping a weak reference to the cell (as you’re doing), inside the network request completion block get a new reference to the cell with the desired indexPath.

In all, your implementation should look like this:

```
static NSString *kCellID = @"homePage”; // defined somewhere else, probably at the top of your .m file


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HomePageCell *cell = (HomePageCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellID];
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[HomePageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellID withDictionary:cellData];
    }
    // here we reset the cell’s imageView image property to nil
    // you can/should also do this inside the subclass implementation by overriding -prepareForReuse
    cell.rootImageView.image = nil;

    // request the remote image and set it as the imageView image property
    [cell.rootImageView setImageWithURLRequest:cell.requestImage placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) 
        {
            // since the response could come back some time after the request, 
            // we need to get a fresh, new reference to the cell (which might 
            // have been dequeued and it’s no longer the same one we got before)
            HomePageCell *aCell = (HomePageCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            aCell.rootImageView.image = image;
        }    failure:nil]

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Also - looks like you’re passing some sort of data dictionary to your cells when created. This is wrong because you are only passing the data for new cells and not for reused/dequeued ones. Try moving the passing of the `cellData` dictionary outside both the cell’s `-init` method and the `if(cell == nil)` block.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `_cell` is a property on your class which is just wrong. **Never** store a cell as a property, it's not meant to be stored! Just create a local variable and assign the image to that. It's also not such a good idea but it should work at least. 
The theory of `UITableView` is you provide the cell **once**, then you don't modify it! If you want, you reload the table view, it will ask you again for the cell and *then* you can modify that way. You should never store any kind of pointer to a `UITableViewCell` or any subclass of it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you get that URL from `cellData`, in which case the problem is that you do not reset this property, so when a cell is reused you are still using the same `cellData` from the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:withDictionary:` method. You should do something like:

```
if(_cell == nil)
{
    _cell = [[HomePageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:kCellID withDictionary:cellData];
} else {
   [_cell setCellData:cellData];
}
```