# lazy loading images in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

My problem is ---- I am using `UITableView` in `custom cell` when load data in `tableview` it is loading description and title also date but not load images in tableview.some times load all images  in one row. When i am using this code scroll is working  good but not load images in `TableView`. I want lazy load concepts. go to below link.

[image]

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  newsobject=(newscustamCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (newsobject ==nil)
   {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"newscustamCell" owner:self options:nil];
   }
    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(q, ^{

         NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image_file"]]];

        /* Fetch the image from the server... */

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            /* This is the main thread again, where we set the tableView's image to
         be what we just fetched. */

         newsobject.allnewsimg.image = img;
    // newsobject.allnewsimg.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

        });

    });

      newsobject.allnewsdes.text=[[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]            objectForKey:@"long_desc"]stringByStrippingTags];

       newsobject.allnewslabel.text=[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]        objectForKey:@"title"];
   ![enter image description here][1] 
        newsobject.timelabel.text=[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];

     return newsobject;
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^{

                NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image_file"]]];

                NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image = image;


        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some `Lib` like `SDWebImage` or `Afnetworking`. `Libs` support lazy load image and auto cache this image.
All you need to do:

```
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url of image"]
                   placeholderImage:nil];
```

Comment: thanks for answered me ,i already done this way and i get images from server.but scrolling is very slow and its struck.

Comment: Hi,I see your example program but its work to me but scrolling is very slow and move to strucks.

Comment: I am getting all data from server and add object to "newsarray" here data in newsarray object . when i run this program all data dislay in tablview (image and long description and data and title also)but when i scroll tablview its very slow and move to strucks because images loading lazy.how can i solve my problem...

Comment: both lib will load and cache image in other thread so not need call dispatch_async. It set simple like set text. If it still slow when scroll check your dequeue reusable code, or if image too large edit lib to cache image in small size or thumbnail. if resize before cache, more image will cache and load from cache is very fast than request to get

Answer (score 0):

I will share you some code. Please follow this code.

First you have to retrieve all data from server. After that load on `tableview`.

Try this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
   NSString *urlString=@"http://put your url";
   self.responseData=[NSMutableData data];
   NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] delegate:self];
   NSLog(@"connection====%@",connection);
}
```

 JSON delegate methods -------------

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  [self.responseData setLength:0];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
  [self.responseData appendData:data];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
  self.responseData=nil;
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSArray *response_Array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseRankData options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary=nil;
    NSDictionary *imgurlDic=nil;
    NSArray *imgDic=nil;

   // I am retrieve image according to my url. So please edit this according to your url. i am just write the format.

    for (int i=0; i < response_Array.count; i++)
    {
        imgurlDic = [imgDic objectAtIndex:i];
        imgDic = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"imageKey"]; // Take your Key according to URL

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgurlDic objectForKey:@"url"]];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        [self.Img_Array addObject:img]; // Adding all image in your image Array.

        NSLog(@"imgurlDic == %@",imgurlDic);
     }

    [self.tableview reloadData]; // reload your tableview here.
}
```

Getting all image in your array you can use this array in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method or where you want to load the images.

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; it will block the UI if image data is bigger. its not lazy loading concept.

Comment: i retrieve 480x1024 size image from url and show on my tableview cell, which framesize is only 40x40. so i think it'll.

Comment: question was about lazy loading concept, you can do the same thing with a background thread. & that will not  block your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way that table view cells are quickly queued/reused, by the time that your network request finishes loading the cell you are referring to might not be the same one you think it is (because it went offscreen and got queued and then reassigned to a different `indexPath`). Also, before returning the cell you need to make sure you reset its `imageView`’s `image` property to `nil` or some default value. See my answer here for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23473911/91458

Also - it’s a good idea to keep a cache of the images you already retrieved. Check the `NSCache` class, which is very similar to using a mutable dictionary but with built in memory management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also used that trick, but the threads and the indexes between threads make a mess so I searched and I found a great library on GitHub.

- [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

You just need to `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>` to your project, and you can define also the placeholder when image is being downloaded with just this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString *CellIdentifier;
        CustomCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        MyObject *object = (MyObject *)[self.list.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        return cell;
}
```

It also cache downloaded images and gives you great performance.

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Hi, i am download and impart this framework but i got one error. i.e. #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h> file not found.

Comment: @user3627091 are you installing it via Cocoa Pods or are you copying folders manually to your project. If you did the second one, you need to import UIImageView+WebCache.h

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link help for you. by using asyn classes image loading async...

https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  newsobject=(newscustamCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: if (newsobject ==nil)
   {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"newscustamCell" owner:self options:nil];
   }
      NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image_file"]]];

Comment: NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
     newsobject.allnewsimg.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

      newsobject.allnewsdes.text=[[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"long_desc"]stringByStrippingTags];

Comment: newsobject.allnewslabel.text=[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"];
        newsobject.timelabel.text=[[newsarry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];

     return newsobject;
   }

Comment: Hi,I am getting all data from server and add object to "newsarray" here data in newsarray object . when i run this program all data dislay in tablview (image and long description and data and title also)but when i scroll tablview its very slow and move to strucks because images loading lazy.how can i solve my problem...

Comment: Hello i got it problem... but u should use AsynImageView classes and load image asyn. we have done it's working fine and tableview is not struck. we are displaying 500 records with image and details labels there is not problem...Do u know how integrate ...